# Replace with different project with ClickOnce update?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, deployment, installation, clickonce

We have an old old WinForm project that was deployed with ClickOnce.

I have just created a new WPF project and planning to deploy with ClickOnce and remove the old WinForm application from all the computers.

Is there a way that I can let all machine when they run the old WinForm application => Check for Update  => Install the new WPF application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is way to code in an implementation for this type of behavior but there is no automatic, easy way to do this.

This has been a bit of an annoyance because any time you need to update a prerequisite or re-publish your application with a new security certificate, the user needs to re-install your application.

To get around this, however, I created a very simple API that you can use to help automate this process.

Check it out [here](http://code.google.com/p/clickonce-application-reinstaller-api/).

Comment: Oh no... your project is in .NET 4.0.... I was thinking if I can modify the old WinForm ClickOnce config file and point to the new one and see if it work. Otherwise I might modify the WinForm application which will execute the install for my new WPF application and my WPF application will uninstall the old WinForm application (somehow...?)

Comment: I think you can down-grade the API from within the project settings.  I don't believe I'm using any properties specific to 4.0.

Comment: Now that I'm looking at the project again, yes, it's written in VS 2010, but the project is targeted for the .Net 2.0 framework.  I assume, that should work for your case.

Comment: Oh, I was debugging your code, I found the error occurs on `HttpWebResponse rsHead = (HttpWebResponse)rqHead.GetResponse();` Not sure why, I guess I might modify your code to work in network drive... maybe is better in my case...

Comment: So the reaosn why GetResponse fail is because IIS doesn't allow access to `reinstall` file, need `txt` file (for me). And I found a bug in your source code: In your `GetUninstallString` method, you executed  `appKey.Close();` to close the RegisteryKey and trying to access `(string)appKey.GetValue("DisplayName");` afterward in the If statement.  That keep on throwing exception, which will only return `Fail uninstall` in result.  But anyway, thanks a lot! Now I can uninstall and install for all machine! +1

Comment: Thanks for the head's up.  I've used this code in a few, personal projects and I've never had that problem.  I'll look into it and see if I can replicate the problem and fix it.